# XmlDocument in place transform with XSL

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm getting abit frustrated trying to find an answer.

Can I perform an XSL transform on a loaded XmlDocument in place? That is, without having to create a writer to the document?

I ask because I have an XmlDocument binding inside a WPF app that I want to sort. The sorts can get a little complicated so XSL seemed a good fit. Here's the code that I'm stuck at:

```
XmlDataProvider xmlDP = (XmlDataProvider)this.Resources["ItemDB"];
string xsltPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XSLDirextory"];
string path = xsltPath + "SortItemName.xslt";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    XslCompiledTransform compTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
    compTrans.Load(path);
    //compTrans.Transform(xmlDP.Document, new XsltArgumentList(), xmlDP.Document.XmlResolver);
}
```

After loading the transform, I'd like to just be able to compTrans(xmlDP.Document); or something that has the same effect. (to be clear, xmlDP.Document is an XmlDocument ) so that the XmlDocument has the result of the transform.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a write to the document? In fact, why not transform from the document to another document, then bind the new document?

Comment: I didn't want to write back to the document because there might be some differences on the in memory copy. If the user closes the app, I don't want those edits to be reflected back into the actual document unless the user explicitly saved to it. As for creating a new document I guess I could, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can do is create a new `XmlDocument` with e.g.

```
XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlWriter xw = result.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
  compTrans.Transform(xmlDP.Document, null, xw);
  xw.Close();
}
```

and then assign that to your property:

```
xmlDP.Document = result;
```

Of course that requires that xmlDP.Document can be set.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT always creates a new document to hold the transformation result, it never modifies the input document.